# Avoid fragment recreation when opening from notification navigation component

Tags: notifications, navigation, fragment

I want when I click on a notification to open a fragment and not recreate it. I am using navigation component and using NavDeepLinkBuilder

```
 val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
            .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.workouts_graph)
            .setDestination(R.id.workoutFragment)
            .createPendingIntent()
```

My case is I have a fragment and when you exit the app, there is a notification which when you click on it, it should return you to that same fragment. Problem is every time i click on it it's creating this fragment again, I don't want to be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Looks like there is not an option to use the NavDeepLinkBuilder without clearing the stack according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDeepLinkBuilder)

I'm not sure the exact nature of your action, but I'll make two assumptions:

1. You pass the destination id to your MainActivity to navigate.
2. Your MainActivity is using ViewBinding and has a NavHostFragment

You will have to create the pending intent like:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            putExtra("destination", R.id.workoutFragment)
}
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

And in your MainActivity, you can handle both cases (app was already open, app was not already open)

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // called when application was not open
    intent?.let { processIntent(it) }
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    // called when application was open
    intent?.let { processIntent(it) }
}

private fun processIntent(intent: Intent) {
    intent.extras?.getInt("destination")?.let {
        intent.removeExtra("destination")
        binding.navHostFragment.findNavController().navigate(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still creating a new fragment since you are navigating from MainActivity to WorkoutFragment.